# after spawning a thread main thread stops?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {   
    try {
        System.out.println("start thread");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SerialReader(event, serialPort,mode));
        thread.start();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("thread engaged");
}
```

Even tough there are no errors while running this code; "thread engaged" is never printed. What could prevent the main thread from continuing to run?

I've tested this by replacing it with

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("OUTPUT");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                };  


            });
```

which works flawlessly.

edit: the only thing happening in the constructor is

```
private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
public SerialReader(ServletContextEvent event, String port, int mode) throws Exception {
   if (mode==1){
   System.out.println("**Mode 1**");
   } else {//mode is 1
   }
   event.getServletContext().setAttribute("serialPortData", queue);
}
```

edit2: (servlet context listener)

```
 private static final String SHUTDOWN_REQ = "SHUTDOWN";
    public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {

        queue = (BlockingQueue<String>) event.getServletContext().getAttribute("serialPortData");

        //we always get a null here on first try that's why I added null check
        if (queue == null){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
        } else {
            String item;
            try {
                //blocks while queue is empty
                while ((item = queue.take()) != SHUTDOWN_REQ) {
                    System.out.println("*******WEB*******"+item+"*******");
                    //TODO Broadcast message to connected clients
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("queue error");
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: `new SerialReader(event, serialPort,mode)`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: That is probably where your execution is stuck (in the constructor of `SerialReader`).

Comment: Okay,thx (I edited the code) but the only thing happening in the constructor is that I set the context of the servlet. No errors are thrown. How is this preventing the main thread from continuing?

Comment: I would try to put a `println` before and after `event.getServletContext().setAttribute("serialPortData", queue);` - my guess is that only the `println` before will get printed.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that. Why do you pass a port and a mode if you don't use them at all? Don't you do anything in a static or instance field declaration that could block the thread?

Comment: May be this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913936/what-causes-my-ui-to-freeze-when-closing-a-serial-port

Comment: @JBNizet Good points - could also be in a static or instance initializer block.

Comment: So the mode is to indicate that I'm not actually using the port; port initialisations are inside the else. In this case mode equals 1. So there is no other code (in the constructor) no. Assylias: yes you're right. When debugging execution stops right there. It then jumps to attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event)

Comment: Do you have any configured servlet context listeners?

Comment: Did you try to debug or profile it. Where exactly is it stuck?

Comment: @Perception: Yes; I'll add the code. (edit: have added the code)

Comment: @Noofiz: Yes I tried debugging; execution just stops when queue is empty.

Comment: Use a debugger or `jstack -l` to grab the stack trace. That'll enable you (and us) to see where exactly it is getting stuck.

Comment: What servlet container are you running this on?

Comment: @ThomasV - you are blocking on the queue in your servlet listener. Hence, why the code never returns from the constructor.

Comment: @Jason Nichols: Jetty 8 and I'm using the atmosphere framework

Comment: @Perception: Yes I'm blocking but my guess was that this shouldn't affect code in another thread.

Comment: @ThomasV - the problem is, there *is* no other thread at the point at which the code is invoked. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are blocking your own code. This expression:

```
new SerialReader(event, serialPort,mode);
```

Requests that a new `SerialReader` be created, but in the constructor you do this:

```
private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("serialPortData", queue);
```

Where `event` is a `ServletContextEvent`. Calling `setAttribute` on it triggers a notification to all attribute listeners on the servlet context. You have such a listener configured with this code:

```
else {
    try {
        //blocks while queue is empty
        while ((item = queue.take()) != SHUTDOWN_REQ)
```

But your queue is not null when this code is executed, so you continuously poll the queue to get items from it, on ***the calling thread***. Thats why your constructor never returns.

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish with the listener, but you probably want to spawn the message sending thread *inside* of it, as opposed to externally the way you are now.

Comment: Thx, Yes that is what is happening. I'm trying to send the data from the serial port to the listener (and then broadcast it to all connected clients using the atmosphere framework). What do you mean by "spawn the message sending thread inside of the listener instead of externally?"

Comment: So I'll just put the blocking part in a new thread. I'll test that now. Thx

Comment: @ThomasV. - yes, thats what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

What is this:

```
(item = queue.take()) != SHUTDOWN_REQ
```

why not

```
!(item = queue.take()).equals(SHUTDOWN_REQ)
```

Or you can do the flowing, and continue comparing strings with != / == :

```
private static final String SHUTDOWN_REQ = "SHUTDOWN".intern();
```

but this is a dirty hack

Comment: The intern thingy won't guarantee that the `==` comparison will work (e.g. `item = new String("SHUTDOWN"); item == SHUTDOWN_REQ` will return false).

Comment: Sure you have to intarnate all strings in this case.